# Performance issues when changing variable in a loop

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, profiling

I have some point in polygon code that is part of a dll that I am calling from python. The code is not executing as quickly as I would hope so I am profiling and attempting to optimize the code.

This is the function in question:

```
int mesh_to_points(const meshobj * mesh, const float * datam, const float * x, const float * y, float * datap, const int np)
{
    float fact[4];
    for (int a=0; a<np; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<mesh->numels; b++)
        {
        element cell = mesh->cell[b];
        if (x[a]>cell.maxx || x[a]<cell.minx || y[a]>cell.maxy || y[a]<cell.miny)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (interp_weights(cell.vx, cell.vy, x[a], y[a], fact, cell.nv))
        {
            datap[a]=b+1.00;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

For the general test I am trying this takes 4.133 seconds to run. When I change the line

```
datap[a]=b+1.00
```

to something like...

```
float cc=b+1.00
```

The total runtime is 0.162 seconds - More in line with how I would like this to run.

I am relatively new to C++ and have only a beginners understanding so far. Is this performance change just down to a smart compiler ? (MSVC in this case) or is there something inherently flawed in the way I am filling the array  "datap" ?

Comment: It's probably not even doing the assignment with cc=b+1, as the value would be immediately thrown away.  Tag it as volatile and see what happens.  That should stop the compiler from optimizing it away: volatile float cc=b+1.0.   Better yet, declare it at the top of your function, not just right inside the if block at the end.

Comment: It seems you are correct. Does this mean that the compiler recognizes that whole if-statement as useless and ignores it? This would suggest that the bottleneck is in the interp_weights function (not unexpected)

Comment: Your options are to either actually profile it, or start tearing pieces out.  make interp_weights be "true" or something and run it again.  Or put interp_weights into a 1-million cycle for loop and see how long it takes to run.  Regardless, volatile is fun, as it instructs the compiler to assume that someone else is going to read that memory without the compiler's knowledge, so it MUST generate all instructions for the variable and do so in order.